# Regex expression with repeating pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I’m having trouble with a regex expression in Ruby 1.8.7.

The string is as follows (the conversation plays out over and over again):

```
recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author john smith (12345) sent 2014-02-04 07:35:32 utc body hi what is your name recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author albert martin (78348734) sent 2014-02-04 07:35:53 utc body my name is albert recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author john smith (12345) sent 2014-02-04 07:36:57 utc body my name is john
```

I need to separate the string into the following matches (keep in mind the conversation could continue - "recipients is the key):

```
recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author john smith (12345) sent 2014-02-04 07:35:32 utc body hi what is your name 

recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author albert martin (78348734) sent 2014-02-04 07:35:53 utc body my name is albert 

recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author john smith (12345) sent 2014-02-04 07:36:57 utc body my name is john
```

Comment: Why not use `String::split`?

Comment: I'm a newbie. Can you explain?

Comment: [`String::split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)splits strings into substrings based on a delimiter.  So, you could do your_str.split("recipients"), and it'll return an array of strings.  But it'll also discard the delimiter in this case.  Give it a try; it's a method worth knowing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd help us if you'd show us the code you've written toward solving this so we can correct what you've written rather than write something from scratch that is unrelated to your code.

Comment: In examples, everything should be expressed as a Ruby object, and you should assign inputs to variables. Here you could write `str = "recipients john smith ... is john"`. Those providing answers can then cut and paste your string, and can refer to `str` in their answers without having to define it. Your desired output should also be a valid Ruby object (e.g., `"recipients john smith ...  what is your name"`), but generally there is no need to assign it to a variable. If you don't do this you will be inviting downvotes and votes to close.

Answer (score 1):

With string split this will split this string by the word 'recipients'. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-ruby for more examples.

```
input = "recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author john smith (12345) sent 2014-02-04 07:35:32 utc body hi what is your name recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author albert martin (78348734) sent 2014-02-04 07:35:53 utc body my name is albert recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author john smith (12345) sent 2014-02-04 07:36:57 utc body my name is john"
input.shift
values = input.split("recipients")
```

When you use this array later remember to add recipients, which are not part of the array.

Comment: That returns `["", " john smith (12345)...what is your name ", " john smith (12345)...my name is albert ", " john smith (12345)...my name is john"]`. Notice the empty string at the beginning and the absence of the word "recipients" in the output.

Comment: you can input.shift to get rid of the first element in the array, and if you know each item starts with recipients you can take that into account later

Comment: That's true, but you haven't answered the question. You need to modify your answer to provide the output the OP has requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression, as follows (where `str` is your string):

```
r = /
    recipients\s        # match text
    .+?                 # match one or more of any character, lazily (?)
    (?=recipients\s|\z) # positive look ahead for string or end of string
    /x                  # extended mode

    str.scan r
      #=> ["recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author \
john smith (12345) sent 2014-02-04 07:35:32 utc body hi what is your name ",
      #    "recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author \
albert martin (78348734) sent 2014-02-04 07:35:53 utc body my name is albert ",
      #    "recipients john smith (12345) albert martin (78348734) author \
john smith (12345) sent 2014-02-04 07:36:57 utc body my name is john"]
```